# Where column value at least 2

Tags: mysql

I have a table

| ID | Name | job | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abby | Janitor | pink |
| 2 | Bob | teacher | yellow |
| 3 | Cam | Musician | blue |
| 4 | Bob | teacher | green |
| 5 | Abby | teacher | pink |

And I want to get the Name of those with the same Job but has at least two different colours

So in this case only Bob would get returned

Comment: Does `(Name, Job)` is defined as UNIQUE? If not, and some Name may have different Job values, then do you need in Name where there are different Color values for at least one of its Job values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name
FROM TblComb
GROUP BY Name,Job
HAVING COUNT(Colour) > 1;
```

Result_Set:

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 1):

We can use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING MIN(job) = MAX(job) AND
       MIN(Colour) <> MAX(Colour);
```

Comment: "those with the same Job" - so I guess it should be `GROUP BY Name, job`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It isn't clear whether a person who has multiple jobs can still qualify assume that two records exist with the same job but different colors.  Assuming not, my update should be correct.

Comment: I agree - the question was not clear. Now with your update it's even more unclear :-) Too much room for interpretation.